# How to repeat calling method in background every day at different times

Tags: ios, swift, background, swift4

I'm working on a prayers times application. I need to call specific method to do some tasks five times a day without forcing user to open the application and without notify him/her. I read that may be I need to let my method running in the background, but I don't know how to trigger it.

any suggestions or solutions?

thank you.

Comment: You can use silent notification for that.

Comment: You can't schedule background tasks for a specific time on iOS. If the task won't notify the user, why does it need to execute at specific times?  You could perform the calculations opportunistically using the background fetch service

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do something on your app if it's not gonna notify your user about a change or so, I would recommend to do this server-side ( if your app has one)

Comment: my idea is that the user voice will be recognized using speech recognition API  five times a day at specific times ,i'll search for these suggestions, thank you